# Unity Physics: How To Limit Rotation of Object Moved by Gravity

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, game-physics, physics-engine

I have a Child object, an **Iron Bar** (with Rigidbody and Gravity), connected to a **Long Arm** (w/ Rigidbody and isKinematic). I need to restrict the rotation of the **Iron Bar** from **1 to 40 degree angles** only so it won't go overboard and hit the **Long Arm**. Please refer to attached image for more info. I tried several approaches from using a **Hinge Joint** and its *Limit* options and also through code. But I cannot seem to solve this problem. Right now I have this script attached to the **Iron Bar** but it does not seem to have any effect.

```
public Transform targetTransform;
private Vector3 _currentAngle;
private Vector3 _targetAngle;
float rotationX;

void FixedUpdate () {

     transform.right = targetTransform.transform.right; //-- To make the Iron Bar follow player rotation

     rotationX = transform.eulerAngles.x;

     if (rotationX > 40) {
         _targetAngle = new Vector3 (40, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
         _currentAngle = new Vector3 (Mathf.LerpAngle (transform.eulerAngles.x, _targetAngle.x, Time.deltaTime), Mathf.LerpAngle (transform.eulerAngles.y, _targetAngle.y, Time.deltaTime), Mathf.LerpAngle (transform.eulerAngles.z, _targetAngle.z, Time.deltaTime));
         transform.eulerAngles = _currentAngle;
     } else if (rotationX < 1) {
         _targetAngle = new Vector3 (1, transform.eulerAngles.y, transform.eulerAngles.z);
         _currentAngle = new Vector3 (Mathf.LerpAngle (transform.eulerAngles.x, _targetAngle.x, Time.deltaTime), Mathf.LerpAngle (transform.eulerAngles.y, _targetAngle.y, Time.deltaTime), Mathf.LerpAngle (transform.eulerAngles.z, _targetAngle.z, Time.deltaTime));
         transform.eulerAngles = _currentAngle;
     }

 }
```

Would appreciate any help you can provide. Thanks for taking a look.

[image: Limit rotation of Iron Bar from 1 to 40 degrees only]

**Note:** This is a revised question but related to the initial one which I have already partially solved. Revision was made for further clarification.

Comment: Made a correction to my question. I realized I need to also rotate ItemHolder in the Z axis while the vehicle is also moving/rotating. Meaning it should follow the movement of the vehicle except the Y-axis rotation. Thus problem is still not solved.

Comment: Edited my question again for simplification and further clarification. I just require the ItemHolder, an object with Gravity and attached to a Hinge Joint object, to follow the correct Player's orientation with regards to rotation and swinging. I'm not sure if I still need to create a script for the ItemHolder object to do this as I am assuming my requirements can already be handled by Unity's Hinge Joint script? That is its purpose right?

Comment: I am guessing Unity's Hinge Joint system is totally messed up and unusable for 2018.1.6. I haven't found anybody else in the Internet who has claimed that they have used it successfully unless its just for ropes and a very simple non moving parent. :-(

Comment: I was able to make the Child object (ItemHolder) follow rotation of the parent Player object by simply using this line of code under FixedUpdate & locking all Rigidbody Constraints of the Child except X Rotation:
transform.right = targetTransform.transform.right;

Comment: That somehow worked but any adjustments to the Hinge Joint script like limiting the rotation (min/max) does nothing & has no effect whatsoever. So my new problem now is how to avoid the Child object from rotating 360 degrees in the X Axis and just limiting it to 0-90 degrees. Anybody knows how to limit the X Rotation of an object through code? Controlling through eulerAngles does not seem to work...

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: To lessen complexity, I removed the Hinge joint and just used Rigibodies. Then I changed the script for the Iron Bar into:

public Transform targetTransform;
    
void FixedUpdate ()
{
     Vector3 rot = transform.rotation.eulerAngles;
     rot.x = Mathf.Clamp (rot.x, 1f, 40f);
     transform.eulerAngles = rot;
}
    
void Update ()
{
     transform.right = targetTransform.transform.right; //-- Follow player L-R rotation
}

Still did not work and no effect. The Iron Bar and child objects still does 360 rotation from time to time. :-(